# summing chars in loop

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to sum the ascii value's of a string from a loop. I think I'm missing something, but I keep either getting wrong values returned at the end of the program (ie. not matching the values i manually summed using the ascii table), or seg faults.

My program:

```
.data                           # .data section begins
name: .ascii "Json"             # name is ASCII chars (.ascii or .byte)
len:  .int 4                    # name length is 4 chars, an integer
newline: .ascii "\n"            # new line character

count: .int 0                   # counter for loop (start at 0)

return: .int 0                  # return code value
tmp: .int 0                     # temp value

.text                           # text section starts
.global _start                  # main program entry

_start:                         # start instruction

again:                          # begin loop

    mov $1, %edx                # 1 byte at a time
    mov $name, %ecx             # mem addr
    add count, %ecx             # offset in string

    #### Trouble area ####

    # this seg faults
    mov count(%ecx), %ebx
    add %ebx, return

    #### Trouble area ####

    mov $1, %ebx                # file descriptor 1 is computer display
    mov $4, %eax                # system call 4 is sys_write (output)
    int $128                    # interrupt 128 is entry to OS services

    add $1, count               # incr count
    mov count, %eax             # copy count to eax
    cmp %eax, len               #   and compare values

    jne again                   # if not equal, goto again

    mov $newline, %ecx          # mem addr

    mov $1, %ebx                # file desc 1
    mov $4, %eax                # sys call 4
    int $128                    # interrupt 128

    mov $1, %eax                # system call 1 is sys_exit
    mov return, %ebx            # status return
    int $128                    # interrupt 128
```

I think I'm missing something basic, but I understand this to be move the value in `ecx` register offset by the value of `count` (ie. loop iteration and therefore the array element), into register `ebx`. Then add the value in `ebx` to `return`. Then at the endof the program, move the summed value that is in `return` to register `ebx` and then call the interrupt. During runtime this seg faults, but I'm unsure why.

I would expect it to not seg fault (obviously lol), and when calling `~]# echo $?` for it to print `410` (ie, 'J' + 's' + 'o' + 'n' or... 74 + 115 + 111 + 110).

`UPDATE:------------>`

I have updated the "trouble spot" to the following per advice from @Michael (if I understood correctly).

```
    #### Trouble area ####

    # this returns a garbage number, 154 instead of 410
    mov count, %edi 
    mov name(%edi), %ebx
    add %ebx, return

    #### Trouble area ####
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that `mov count(%ecx), %ebx` does. What it _will try_ to do is take the address of `count`, add the value of `ecx`, load a 32-bit value from the resulting address and store it in `ebx`. In other words; you're accessing `count` as if it was an array, even though it's declared as a single `int`.

Comment: @Michael thank you. I was under the impression that `someNumber(%someregister)` was using base-pointer addressing mode, ie, `someNumber` is your offset of the memory address location in the `(%someregister)`. I think I"m trying to access it like an array... I tried using indexed addressing mode, ie. `mov name(,%ecx,1), %edi` but this also does not work.

Comment: @Michael I have just posted a revision to my original code (this time only the snippet in question. I no longer get a seg fault, but instead back to getting garbage output (wrong number).

Comment: What do you mean by _"output"_? It doesn't look like you're printing any numbers anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Michael sorry, I meant the return value. After running the program, issuing the `~]# echo $?` from the terminal should fetch that returned value, ie. 410.

Comment: to elaborate @Michael, each iteration of the loop adds the value of the current character being printed, to the sum stored in the label `return`. At the end of the program, I move the value in `return` to `%ebx` and then call the system to exit. This makes the value in `return` at the end of the program, the return value accessible from the OS using `echo $?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exit codes

POSIX exit status codes are effectively an unsigned byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)410);
    return 410;
}
```

This will both print and return `154`, which is `410 % 256`.

Read the POSIX section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX

### Other ways of getting the value

1. You can run your process in gdb and use `i r` to print the register contents, or `print return`.
2. You can convert your int into a string [1] and call the `write` syscall [2] on stdout with a pointer to the resulting string (`write(1, "string\n", len)`).

[1] *integer to string*: mod 10 to get rightmost digit, divide by 10 to remove the rightmost digit, repeat until n = 0, then reverse the string *or* do a call to `sprintf()`, `itoa()`, etc

[2] http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html#Syscalls

Comment: wow, you're right. the "garbage' i'm getting **is** 154! Does this mean I need to change my `return` label to be a `.byte` instead of `.int`? (also, i'm not allowed to use the c lib, only native asm calls in GAS).

Comment: You can't return the value 410 in a byte, which has a maximum value of 255. You can make a `write` syscall without touching C by putting some values in registers and doing `int $0x80` (which you already do for sys_exit). Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: hmm, i need to fetch the value from outside the program (ie. `echo $?` which gets the return value from the most recently run program. Putting a value into `%ebx` and then calling to exit the program sets this "return value". calling `int 0x80` i understand will print to the screen from within the program. sorry, i'm trying to be clear but am pretty new to GAS asm.

Comment: You cannot get a value greater than 255 using the exit status on Linux. `int 0x80` is the same as `int $128`, it just means you're calling the syscall interrupt. There are many syscalls.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry to ask this, but perhaps you could interpret these instructions for me?

`3. During the loop, add the ASCII value of the current character
displayed into a sum (set to zero before the loop, of course).`  ..  `5. Put the sum into ebx (return code to shell) at the end
of the program when calling exit (see example programs).
After running, enter shell command echo $? to see the sum
and verify with your own hand calculation.`

.. at this point, it's obvious this is an assignment, lol.

Comment: I understand this to mean, i need to sum the char's value in my loop,  then at the end of my program, set that summed value as the return status, which will make it available to the shell.

Comment: Sounds about right, but you still won't be able to return values over 255. I'd guess either learning about status codes is part of the exercise, or your teacher didn't realize this.

Comment: oh geeze... I just realized he updated the instructions late last night! he originally had said to pick a 4 characters string so the total value would be < 1000, but today he's updated to say 3 chars and to use only upper case so that it's sum is 255 or less (exactly as you pointed out). wow, banging my head on a wall for no reason!  A big big thank you for your help and advice. I appreciate it.